# how to setup mail exchange to send out email from xampp

Tags: email, xampp, exchange-server

I would like to send out notification from my php website. However I am using exchange. When I set up in sendmail.ini and php.ini. I dono what to key in for the smtp for my email exchange.
I would like to send out notification from my php website. However I am using exchange. When I set up in sendmail.ini and php.ini. I dono what to key in for the smtp for my email exchange.

I would like to send out notification from my php website. However I am using exchange. When I set up in sendmail.ini and php.ini. I dono what to key in for the smtp for my email exchange.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange server is an SMTP server like all other internet e-mail servers.
Use the host name of your Exchange server, and port 25 or 465 (for SMTP/SSL).

Perhaps your Exchange server requires authentication. That is normal if you want to send to outside domains. In that case, you need to configure that as well.

You should ask your Exchange admins for the details, if you don't have them.